# Code Markdown bug

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

I've only seen this happen on music.se, the latest one on [Metronome Sound](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/121636/metronome-sound) today.
The last code block on a page renders as a blank box.

It looks like a few people have had different attempts to get the last code block on the page to render correctly. The first block has no issues. Individual elements marked as `code` also seem unaffected. If you refresh the page it briefly appears correctly, then breaks half a second later. It looks fine in the editor as it's being constructed.
I've tried to clear this one down & regenerate it to avoid any non-standard characters. No effect.

I'll test copy paste of it below, see what happens...

```
BPM = 100
cl--cl--cl
```

Appears to render fine in here.
Screenshot of the affected page, in case others cannot repro.

> [image]

The current version of the linked page now has one fixed using `<pre>` blocks & the last one left 'broken' - so users on Music.se can actually see the question as asked & not have to play with the code blocks themselves in order to read it.

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in Music.SE's [jTab extension](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/19800), which becomes apparent when you analyze the source code of e.g. [this revision page](https://music.stackexchange.com/revisions/121636/5):

[image]

I'm not sure under which conditions the extension is activated for a code block, but I guess it interprets the hyphens as part of the tab. I see you fixed it already, but another option would be to try replacing them by other sorts of dashes?

Comment: I've just re-edited it so you can see it in 2 instances 'fixed' & 'broken'. You can fix it with `<pre>` tagging, but not everybody knows the various ways of forcing format. html, css & the like mean nothing to me, I'm afraid.